# algo class question: compare n no. of sequence showing their comparison which leads to the particular sequence

Tags: algorithm

Whenever you compare 3 no. it end up in 6 results and similarly 4 no it goes for 24 no. making permutation of no. of inputs.

The task is to compare n no. of sequence showing their comparison which leads to the particular sequence

For example your input is a,b,c

```
If a<b
  If b<c
    Abc
    Else
      If a<c
          Acb
      Else a>c
          cab
 Else b>c
    Cba
    Else
       If a<c
          Bac
       Else
          Bca
   Else
      Cba
```

The task is to print all the comparisons which took place to lead that sequence for n no.s and
confirm that there is no duplication.

Comment: StackOverflow is *not* a homework service, you can ask specific questions about specific problems with *your* attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: I don't understand what your task is.  Furthermore, giving homework answers is a bad idea

Comment: If you use the code tags with your code, fix it up a bit and tell us what kind of language and compiler / interpreter you are using I'm sure you'll get more help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I recommend reading [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It explains the importance of the title of a question. Once you've read that, you should come back and [edit] this question to give it a proper title which gives an indication what the question is about (because this title doesn't).

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to build a [sorting network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network) in code. You might also be interested in the Bose-Nelson sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is Python code that outputs valid Python code to assign to `answer` the sorted values.

The sorting algorithm here is mergesort.  Which is not going to give the smallest possible decision tree, but it will be pretty good.

Here is Python code that outputs valid Python code to assign to `answer` the sorted values.

The sorting algorithm here is mergesort.  Which is not going to give the smallest possible decision tree, but it will be pretty good.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys

class Tree:
    def __init__ (self, node_type, value1=None, value2=None, value3=None):
        self.node_type = node_type
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2
        self.value3 = value3

    def output (self, indent='', is_continue=False):
        rows = []
        if self.node_type == 'answer':
            rows.append("{}answer = [{}]".format(indent, ', '.join(self.value1)))
        elif self.node_type == 'comparison':
            if is_continue:
                rows.append('{}elif {} < {}:'.format(indent, self.value1[0], self.value1[1]))
            else:
                rows.append('{}if {} < {}:'.format(indent, self.value1[0], self.value1[1]))
            rows = rows + self.value2.output(indent + '  ')
            if self.value3.node_type == 'answer':
                rows.append('{}else:'.format(indent))
                rows = rows + self.value3.output(indent + '  ')
            else:
                rows = rows + self.value3.output(indent, True)
        return rows

# This call captures a state in the merging.
def _merge_tree (chains, first=None, second=None, output=None):
    if first is None and second is None and output is None:
        if len(chains) < 2:
            return Tree('answer', chains[0])
        else:
            return _merge_tree(chains[2:], chains[0], chains[1], [])
    elif first is None:
        return _merge_tree(chains + [output])
    elif len(first) == 0:
        return _merge_tree(chains, second, None, output)
    elif second is None:
        return _merge_tree(chains + [output + first])
    elif len(second) < len(first):
        return _merge_tree(chains, second, first, output)
    else:
        subtree1 = _merge_tree(chains, first[1:], second, output + [first[0]])
        subtree2 = _merge_tree(chains, first, second[1:], output + [second[0]])
        return Tree('comparison', [first[0], second[0]], subtree1, subtree2)
def merge_tree (variables):
    # Turn the list into a list of 1 element merges.
    return _merge_tree([[x] for x in variables])

# This captures the moment when you're about to compare the next
# variable with the already sorted variable at position 'position'.
def insertion_tree (variables, prev_sorted=None, current_variable=None, position=None):
    if prev_sorted is None:
        prev_sorted = []

    if current_variable is None:
        if len(variables) == 0:
            return Tree('answer', prev_sorted)
        else:
            return insertion_tree(variables[1:], prev_sorted, variables[0], len(prev_sorted))
    elif position < 1:
        return insertion_tree(variables, [current_variable] + prev_sorted)
    else:
        position = position - 1
        subtree1 = insertion_tree(variables, prev_sorted, current_variable, position)
        subtree2 = insertion_tree(variables, prev_sorted[0:position] + [current_variable] + prev_sorted[position:])
        return Tree('comparison', [current_variable, prev_sorted[position]], subtree1, subtree2)

args = ['a', 'b', 'c']
if 1 < len(sys.argv):
    args = sys.argv[1:]
for line in merge_tree(args).output():
    print(line)
```

For giggles and grins, you can get insertion sort by switching the final call to `merge_tree` to `insertion_tree`.

In principle you could repeat the exercise for any sort algorithm, but it gets really tricky, really fast.  (For quicksort you have to do continuation passing.  For heapsort and bubble sort you have to insert fancy logic to only consider parts of the decision tree that you could actually arrive at.  It is a fun exercise if you want to engage in it.)